# Unable to do a full maximize of the Firefox window?

Tags: 14.04, firefox

Something weird happens to Firefox (37.0.2) after some time (probably days) has elapsed into its start and it does not maximize fully anymore. Neither with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> or the maximize key. And this is the case with all the windows of Firefox.

By fully maximize I mean the window frame doesn't disappear/merge with the top panel.

The only solution I know of is restart Firefox. Any other alternative to this that doesn't involve a restart?

Picture for elaboration:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One solution which could be equivated with restarting Firefox/FF (debatable) is:

If you have one FF window open then do the following:

1. Open new window <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>
2. Switch to previous window
3. Close the window <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>
4. Reopen the window <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>
5. Close the new window (optional)

If you have more than one window open then only do 3 and 4 of the above.

Basically opening a new window instance fixes the problem.